# Jenkinsfile clone bitbucket repo from .sh script

Tags: git, jenkins, bitbucket

I need to automate a script in jenkins. the script is owned by another department so we have no authority to change it. the script basically has a step where it runs a git clone [https://bitbucket.org/{repo}.git](https://bitbucket.org/%7Brepo%7D.git).

I'm using a withCredentials gitusernamePassword which is not working. It says authentication failed. When i try to run the git clone manually and passing the username in the URL it works https://USERNAME@bitbucket.org/{repo}.git. Any ideas how i can set that up by default ? I tried setting the following which didn't work

git config --global user.name
git config --global user.email

Answer (score 0):

`Username and password` is a deprecated authentication method for API and Git operations in the Bitbucket. You may want to use SSH keys instead of username and password.

As document pointed ;
`Starting Sep 13, 2021, new Bitbucket users will not be able to use their personal Atlassian account password when using Basic authentication with the Bitbucket API or Git over HTTPS. They will need to use Bitbucket app passwords. Bitbucket users who created an Atlassian account before September 13, 2021 will be able to use their Atlassian account password to authenticate with the Bitbucket API or Git until March 1, 2022.`

Reference : https://bitbucket.org/blog/deprecating-atlassian-account-password-for-bitbucket-api-and-git-activity

Comment: I'm using an app password.

Comment: Did you see this thread ? https://community.atlassian.com/t5/Bitbucket-questions/How-to-configure-an-app-password-in-Jenkins/qaq-p/1448688

Comment: Yes, all the solutions are to add the USERNAME { &password } to the URL. As i stated i have no control to change the URL. the URL is embedded inside a script the development teams own.